# Creating a customer OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

Trying to create a customer `OnclickListener` in a `Numbers.java` file.

My code is

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Max on 06.01.2017.
 */

public class Numbers implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View view){
        Intent IntentEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        IntentEmail.setType("message/rfc822");
        IntentEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"mailto@gmail.com"});
        if (IntentEmail.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!= null){
            startActivity(IntentEmail);
        }
    }
}
```

However, it tells me it cannot resolve the methods `startActivity` and `getPackageManager`.

When I create the `OnClickListener` inline in `MainActivity.java` it works.
What could be the problem?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Those methods are from the `Context` class. That's why you're not able to call them. You can only call it from classes which extends `Context (Activity or Service)`. What you could do is use the context from the `View`.

Like this:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Max on 06.01.2017.
 */

public class Numbers implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View view){
        Context context = view.getContext();
        Intent IntentEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        IntentEmail.setType("message/rfc822");
        IntentEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"mailto@gmail.com"});
        if (IntentEmail.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager())!= null){
            context.startActivity(IntentEmail);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`StartActivity` is a method of `Context` class. Your Number class is not extending `Context` so you don't have accessibility to this method. Same thing for `getPackageManager`.

When you create the `OnClickListener` inline in the `MainActivity` you are in `MainActivity` context, so you can use there methods, because you are referring to `MainActivity` object.

Comment: thank you! With the answers above and below I understand my problem!

Answer (score 1):

[startActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) and [getPackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageManager()) both method is from `Context` class so need to use Context class instance to access it.

> When i create the OnclickListener inline in the MainActivity.java it
>   works. What could be the problem?

Because `Activity` is subclass of `Context` class, so we are able to access all  methods from Context class using `this`.

**Solution :**

From every View instance we can get current valid `Context` by calling [getContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()).

So use `view` parameter of `onClick` method to access both methods.like:

```
view.getContext().startActivity(IntentEmail);
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. Used your answer in combination with the first answer!